# How to pass XML content to Pandas in Python

Tags: python, xml, pandas

I have many XML files, and want to create a DF with the content of them. How can I create a DF to store the "Fundo", "CNPJ" and "Quantidade" from the sample bellow?

**EDIT:**

Here is a link to download a XML file like the ones I want to read:

https://fnet.bmfbovespa.com.br/fnet/publico/downloadDocumento?id=113925

Here is the code I already Tried:

```
def informes_tri_xml_read():
    Dados = pd.DataFrame([])
    folder = os.listdir(DVD_XML)
    for file in folder:
        #print(file)
        try:
            if file.endswith('.xml'):
                with open(os.path.join(DVD_XML, file), encoding="utf8") as fd:
                    doc = xmltodict.parse(fd.read())
                    if 'Emissor' in doc['DadosEconomicoFinanceiros']['InformeTrimestral']['InfoTipoAtivo']['AtivosFinanceiros']['FII'].keys():
                        NomeFundo = doc['DadosEconomicoFinanceiros']['DadosGerais']['NomeFundo']
                        CNPJFundo = doc['DadosEconomicoFinanceiros']['DadosGerais']['CNPJFundo']
                        Mandato = doc['DadosEconomicoFinanceiros']['DadosGerais']['Autorregulacao']['Mandato']
                        DataTri = doc['DadosEconomicoFinanceiros']['DadosGerais']['DataEncerTrimestre']

                        FiiNome = doc['DadosEconomicoFinanceiros']['InformeTrimestral']['InfoTipoAtivo']['AtivosFinanceiros'][
                            'FII']['Emissor']['Fundo']
                        CNPJ = doc['DadosEconomicoFinanceiros']['InformeTrimestral']['InfoTipoAtivo']['AtivosFinanceiros'][
                            'FII']['Emissor']['CNPJ']
                        Quantidade = doc['DadosEconomicoFinanceiros']['InformeTrimestral']['InfoTipoAtivo']['AtivosFinanceiros'][
                            'FII']['Emissor']['Quantidade']
                    print(CNPJ)
```

**Problem:**

It is printing only the first element with "CNPJ", and not the list of "CNPJ" that is bellow the "Emissor" under "FII".

How can i Iterate through all the "Emissor" to print all the different data under it?

Comment: there is a special package for reading xml files, https://pypi.org/project/pandas-read-xml/

Comment: 1) upload a valid xml 2) share your current effort with us

Comment: @balderman i edited the question as you sugested, can you take a look?

Comment: Did you look and try to adopt my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<r><Emissor>
    <Fundo>REAL ESTATE FUND I</Fundo>
    <CNPJ>11.839.09</CNPJ>
    <Quantidade>118650</Quantidade>
    <Valor>10443573</Valor>
</Emissor>
<Emissor>
    <Fundo>X REAL ESTATE FUND I</Fundo>
    <CNPJ>X 11.839.09</CNPJ>
    <Quantidade>X 118650</Quantidade>
    <Valor>X 10443573</Valor>
</Emissor></r>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
data = []
for em in root.findall('.//Emissor'):
    entry = {}
    for prop in ['Fundo','CNPJ','Quantidade']:
        entry[prop] = em.find(prop).text
    data.append(entry)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

output

```
                  Fundo         CNPJ Quantidade
0    REAL ESTATE FUND I    11.839.09     118650
1  X REAL ESTATE FUND I  X 11.839.09   X 118650
```

Comment: How should i pass the xml file instead of the writen xml in to the python?

Comment: ET.parse('file.xml')